# How do I use the NumberFormat & maxDecimalFraction() functions?

Tags: android

I want to format the text sent to a edittext box so that at most 2 decimal places are shown, e.g. XXX.00. From the developer.android site I've been able to create the format variable (or is it a enum?) as follows:

```
NumberFormat nf = new NumberFormat;
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
```

I tried to format my string s = nf.format(s); but it doesn't work.
How do I format a string vaiable with the nf to prepare it for a edittext box?

Also, how am I supposed to figure this out from the developers.android site for "NumberFormat"? Is there a way to read the site to figure this out, or is the site simply incomplete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. Your code looks incomplete. The [NumberFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html) documentation looks complete to me.

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(); // get instance for your locale
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2); // set decimal places
String s = nf.format(100.0232); // the parameter must be a long or double
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it! I was feeding the format with a string instead of a double. I'm still puzzled on how to use the developers.android refences. I stole the nf.format() from the web. How should I read the android site to get this?

Answer (score 1):

I have created a method that I use for formatting my text:

```
public static String formatDouble(double doubleToFormat, int min, int max) {
NUMBER_FORMAT.setMaximumFractionDigits(max);
NUMBER_FORMAT.setMinimumFractionDigits(min);
return NUMBER_FORMAT.format(doubleToFormat);
}
```

Here is my `NUMBER_FORMAT` field:

```
public static final NumberFormat NUMBER_FORMAT = NumberFormat.getInstance();
```

And to use it:

```
myEditText.setText(formatDouble(153.141254, 2, 2));
```

result text in `myEditText`: 153.14

using this function(`formatDouble`), you can send any **min** or **max** value you desire